# I want to click a button to toggle div slideUp & slideDown and quick anywhere else on the page to close the div

Tags: jquery

I have a button #clickme. When clicked a div #cart slides up, when clicked again it slides down.

I also want to be able to close it by clicking anywhere else on the page apart from #cart or #clickme.

The code I've attempted doesn't quite work. What happens now is that when I click #clickme, it slides up and then back down again quickly.

I imagine what is happening is that the click event is triggered at both the document and #clickme levels, causing one effect after the other.

What's an elegant way around this?

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
   if ($("#cart").is(":hidden")) {
       $("#cart").slideDown("slow");
   } else {
       $("#cart").slideUp("slow");
   }
});

$(document.body).click(function () {
   if ($("#cart").not(":hidden")) {
       $("#cart").slideUp("slow");
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [jAndy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305000/jandy) states the problem is event bubbling here, but you since you asked "is there a more elegant way", yes there is :)

If we take advantage of [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) and the [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/), your code comes very terse indeed, you can do this:

```
$('#clickme').click(function(e) {
  $("#cart").stop(true, true).slideToggle("slow");
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function () {
  $("#cart:visible").stop(true, true).slideUp("slow");
});
```

[`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) does *almost* exactly the check you're doing,  The difference is it checks when it gets there, so in the case of queued animations it's even better.  And by using [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) we're only selecting `#cart` if it's visible and needs sliding up, otherwise there's nothing selected.  The [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) call is just to prevent animation queue-up for fast clicks, test it out and see what behavior you want, this part is optional.

And last the [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) call is to prevent the click event from  bubbling up to document and triggering it's [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler, ([click here for more info on that](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)).

Comment: this is cool, I even didn't add anything on that code and it worked best.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're binding a `click event` to the `document.body`, your `click event` bound to `#clickme` **bubbles up** to the document and triggers your handler there.

You need to call `.stopPropagation()` within your `#clickme` event handler:

```
$('#clickme').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();

   if ($("#cart").is(":hidden")) {
       $("#cart").slideDown("slow");
   } else {
       $("#cart").slideUp("slow");
   }
});
```

That will prevent the `click event` bubbling up the DOM.

Sitenote: You should seriously have a read about **Caching DOM references**. You're querying the exact same element like 6 times in that little piece of code. Do it once

```
var $cart = $('#cart');
```

and use `$cart` from there on. A lot of performance can be gained there.

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/EuzyL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var toggleThis = function() {
   if ($("#cart").is(":hidden")) {
       $("#cart").slideDown("slow");
   } else {
       $("#cart").slideUp("slow");
   }
};

$('#clickme').click(toggleThis);
$('#clickme').blur(toggleThis);

$(document.body).click(function () {
   if ($("#cart").not(":hidden")) {
       $("#cart").slideUp("slow");
   } 
});
```

Happy Coding.